# Envieux ou Jaloux

Tags: sens, choix-de-mot, synonymes

Existe-t-il une nuance entre être envieux et être jaloux ?

D'après Larousse.fr

> **Envieux** : Qui manifeste une envie, malveillante ou non, à l'égard de quelqu'un, qui éprouve du dépit à cause de quelque chose ; jaloux

Envieux est donc considéré comme un synonyme de jaloux.

> **Jaloux** : Qui
>   éprouve un vif sentiment d'envie devant l'avantage, le succès, le bien de quelqu'un d'autre ; qui manifeste cet état d'esprit, cette envie

Pourtant j'ai l'impression qu'être jaloux implique le désir de voir l'autre perdre ou ne plus avoir accès à l'objet de la convoitise. Alors qu'être envieux exprime simplement le fait d'avoir envie de la même chose, sans pour autant souhaiter qu'autrui n'en dispose pas.

Cette nuance est-elle réelle ?

Comment: Pour faire simple, on utilisera "envieux" lorsqu'on désire ce que l'on a pas (dans ce sens, "jaloux" convient aussi). Pour quelque chose qu'on possède, mais qu'on ne veut pas partager, seul "jaloux" peut convenir.

Comment: What @Graffito said! This is the difference, IMO, in French. In English "*jealousy*" and "*envy*" are more closely synonymous. But IMO in French there is a clear difference, which Graffito expressed well.

Comment: That's what I thought but considering @cram2208's answer, that not really the case

Comment: Envieux=tu veux ce que l'autre a (possède) que tu n'as pas; jaloux=tu veut être l'autre ou comme l'autre. Je lui envie sa voiture. [je veux sa voitre] Je suis jaloux de lui; il a une belle femme. [J'aimerais être ce type pour "avoir" sa femme]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bonjour !

Si on se fie au Wiktionnaire qui retrace l'étymologie jusqu'aux langues anciennes:

**Envieux**:

Le mot envieux a un long parcours étymologique au travers du latin. Ce mot descend directement de ***invidiosus*** qui veut dire **plein d'envie**. Si on recule sur les origines d'envie donc ***invidia***, on obtient **malveillance, haine** voire **envie, jalousie** et de part son étymologie *invidia*, **ne** ou **ne pas (*in-*) veiller à (*vidia*)**, donc plein de malveillance. Somme toute, je dirais qu'envieux a à la fois un sens positif et négatif.

---

**Jaloux**:

Le mot jaloux à un parcours étymologique plus court. Ce mot descend directement de ***zelosus*** qui veut dire **plein de zèle** et le **zèle** selon le [Wiktionnaire](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/z%C3%A8le):

> Vive ardeur pour appliquer les consignes et les règlements à la
>   lettre, ou plus généralement pour le maintien ou le succès de quelque
>   chose en poussant à l’extrême le travail sans prendre la moindre
>   initiative pour l’alléger en l’interprétant.

Donc la jalousie consiste à être prêt à faire tout ce qu'on peut pour obtenir le résultat escompté sans ménager quelque effort que ce soit.

---

Le verdict: **envieux** et **jaloux** partagent certains points communs comme l'obstination à réaliser l'objectif qui motive l'envie ou la jalousie. Par contre, la nuance semble provenir du fait qu'**envieux** semble impliquer une connotation parfois négative qui ne semble pas se retrouver en **jaloux**.

Afin de revenir directement à ta question

> Cette nuance est-elle réelle ?

Eh bien oui, elle est bien réelle, sauf qu'étymologiquement, la nuance semble être à l'opposé de ta logique (et de la mienne, et de celle de la société en général) et la définition de l'un renvoie souvent à la définition de l'autre.

Comment: Effectivement l'étymologie va à l'encontre du ressenti "naturel" par rapport à ces deux mots. Leurs sens ont aussi beaucoup évolués.

Comment: J'imagine que leur signification dans le temps a été modifiée à maintes reprises. Tandis que l'étymologie de ces deux termes n'est pas nécessairement évaluée par la personne qui l'utilise.

Answer (score 4):

"j'ai l'impression qu'être jaloux implique le désir de voir l'autre perdre ou ne plus avoir accès à l'objet de la convoitise. Alors qu'être envieux exprime simplement le fait d'avoir envie de la même chose, sans pour autant souhaiter qu'autrui n'en dispose pas. Cette nuance est-elle réelle ?" (Hakim)

Oui, cette nuance existe.

En plus de cette nuance, on emploiera ces mots dans des contextes différents. En particulier, "jaloux" s'emploie dans le contexte amoureux ou affectif. On dira par exemple : Monsieur A a beaucoup de succès auprès de Mademoiselle B ; Monsieur C en éprouve de la jalousie / est jaloux de Monsieur A. Plutôt que : ...en éprouve de l'envie / est envieux.

Answer (score 2):

What an interesting question!

I went through a brief cursory review of dictionary input for basic validation before dashing off this quick post. I can't find anything major beyond the level of the differences in the definitions you already posted (possibly I did not search long enough?). This surprises me because I also feel there is a more significant difference between the two.

On the other hand, many words carry implicit connotations at a given time in our collective culture that are not always recognized by dictionaries (I am not a follower of General Semantics, but I always thought there was truth to the "the map is not the territory" aphorism).

Without being able to prove it by a more rigorous analysis of uses in literature, I suggest that the following difference may apply:

- "envious" implies a attitude where reason, calculation planning are more involved, where the individual may purposely dissemble, sneaky behavior is possibly involved; pettiness is implied by the descriptor.
- "jealous" implies a strong emotional reaction, more impulsive, possibly with a flare in behavior.

EDIT: sorry, I meant "envieux" and "jaloux" in the text above. I wrote a little too fast... Thanks to jliagre for the correction!

Comment: While we would certainly agree there must not be that much difference in that particular case, it is quite common for French words adopted by English to slightly diverge as the time goes. Your reply is comparing "envious" and "jealous", something technically off topic here, while the actual question is about "envieux" and "jaloux". You might want to append a French translation of your reply to fix that.

Comment: My goodness, I did not notice I had written them in English, thanks so much for letting me know! I edited the post with a terminal EDIT per your comment.

Answer (score 0):

> - L'*envieux* est *avide, cupide* ; il a *envie de posséder*
> - Le *jaloux* se réfère à l'autre à celui (ou celle) *qui a plus que lui*.

Mais ces deux attitudes révèlent une pulsion de possession puissante.

Une envie existe par elle-même, une jalousie est une envie qui se réfère à une situation vis-à-vis d'un tiers.

L'envieux a envie d'avoir une piscine dans son jardin parce que les voisins en ont une.
S'il est marié, il peut avoir envie de tromper sa femme, s'il ne l'est pas il peut  avoir envie de se marier.

Le jaloux aura envie d'une piscine, mais plus grande ou plus coûteuse que celle de ses voisins.
S'il est marié il sera jaloux du voisin qui a une femme plus belle que la sienne, sinon il sera jaloux de l'acteur marié à son actrice préférée.

Answer (score 0):

J'utilise ces mots de cette façon (francophone de Belgique) :

- une personne **envieuse** a envie de posséder ce qu'une autre personne possède sans nécessairement vouloir qu'elle ne le possède plus.
- une personne **jalouse** craint qu'une autre personne s'approprie ce qu'elle possède, et donc craint de perdre ce qu'elle possède.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).